# ReactJS - Multiple elements sharing the same states

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

So I have 4 panels inside this `Collapse` from ant design and all 4 of them share the same states.
Here's the code for the `Collapse`:

```js
const CustomCollapse = (props) => {
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);
  const [followed, setFollowed] = useState(false);
  const [opened, setOpen] = useState(false);
  let [key, setKey] = useState([props.keys]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setFollowed(props.isFollowed)
  }, [props.isFollowed])

  const handlePanel= () => setOpen(prev => !prev);
  const handlePanelClose = () => props.setShow(prev => !prev);

  const combineFunc = () =>{
    handlePanel();
    handlePanelClose();
  }

  return (
    <StyledCollapse accordian activeKey={props.show ? key : []} onChange={combineFunc}> 
      <AntCollapse.Panel
        {...props}
        header={props.header}
        showArrow={false}
        bordered={false}
        key={props.keys}
        extra={
          <span>
            <span style={{float: 'right'}}>
              {followed ? <img src={tickIcon} alt="" style={{height:'1.2em', marginLRight:'10px', width:'auto', objectFit:'contain'}} /> :  ""}
            </span>
            <div className={styles.extraContainer}>
              {
                !opened && !followed && <div id={styles.themeBox}><p>+10</p></div>  // show this box
              }
              {
                opened && !followed && <img src={arrowDownIcon} alt="" style={{height:'1.2em', marginLRight:'10px', width:'auto', objectFit:'contain'}} />  // show this icon
              }
            </div>
          </span>
        }
      >
      {props.children}
      </AntCollapse.Panel>
    </StyledCollapse>
  );
};
```

Here's the code in father component which uses `Custom Collapse` which is imported as `AntCollapse`:

```js
<AntCollapse isFollowed={followed} show={show} keys="1" setShow={setShow} id={styles.telegramHeader1} header="Follow XXX on Telegram">
   <Row type='flex' align='middle' justify='center'>
      <Button href={links} target="_blank" style={buttonStyle1} onClick={() => setClicked(false)}>
              <Icon type="link" style={{ color: '#fff' }} theme="outlined" />
              Subscribe
      </Button>
   </Row>
   <span className={styles.greyLine}> </span>
   <Row type='flex' align='middle' justify='center'>
      <Button onClick={() => {handleFollow(); handleShow(); }} style={buttonStyle2} disabled={clicked}>Continue</Button> 
    </Row>
</AntCollapse>
```

I have 4 similar AntCollapse and I only show 1 of them here cause all 4 of them use **followed** and **show**. And whenever I expand the panel and click continue, all 4 of them are set to `followed` and `show`. How do I change the states seperately?

Comment: Trey, can you create some fiddle for this?